# Automatically stamp date only in MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to add a column in MySQL to stamp the DATE only? I know that `now()` can be used in the sql to do this. But I'm looking for a way that the database itself automatically adds the date (yyyy-mm-dd) when a record is being added? In my case the time is not necessary, therefore I would rather store the date only (not sure if this a bad practise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below function, which will provide you only date. you can pass through your application-

curdate()

If you want from database itself then keep it -

```
timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
```

Now you can fetch only date by date(mycolumn) function.

Answer (score 1):

set the column type like `timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and it will automatically set the date. Unfortunately it will set the time too. However; you can manipulate the value with php.

PHP

```
echo date ('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['created_time']));
```

Comment: yes, Unfortunatelly it will set the time too. But you can manipulate the string with php function date()

Comment: thanks for that edit. @ZafarMalik 's answer seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Also work with insert:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, date) VALUES (1,DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Comment: thanks. I'm looking for a way that the database itself automatically adds the date (yyyy-mm-dd) when a record is being added.